# Removing .html from URL via htaccess (static website)

Tags: jquery, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a simple static website with 10 html pages and I would like to "clean" the URLs for aesthetic reasons since it's not a *commercial* page or anything. I tried with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

but to no avail. Every link within the website is still displayed with .html and the ones with jquery scroll events leave the # as well.

The website is in the subdirectory in the public_html folder, and it's setup to work via subdirectory.xyz.com but as soon as the page loads it changes the URL from the aforementioned format to xyz.com/subdirectory - is this something that could be sorted via htaccess as well?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```